# creating an array of format array[][@"string"];

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I am trying to create an array similar to the one that is created like this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com/j.php"]];
NSError *error = nil;
if (jsonData) {
     result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                error:&error];
}
```

where `www.example.com/j.php` Is JSON that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"matt","genre":"Photography","info":"foo","date":"2014-06-12"},{"name":"jamie","genre":"Art","info":"Bar","date":"2014-06-13"}]
```

This array is then used like

```
result[indexPath.row][@"name"];
```

**How can I build a new NSArray with my own name, genre and info that is in the same format as the one above??**

---

I have tried to print the array using logs but it comes up as `(null)`

and I know I do not create it like this:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", nil]
```

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then understand that a JSON "array" maps to an NSArray while a JSON "object" maps to an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.

```
NSArray *tmp = @[@{@"name": @"matt", @"genre" : @"Photography"}, @{@"name": @"jamie", @"genre" : @"Art"}];
```

You have to create it using the given example.

Comment: You are incorrect on that last update.  You *can* access an NSDictionary using `[]` notation, in later versions of iOS.

Comment: That error message is coming from the NSLog you're surrounding it all with.

Comment: Thank you @YogeshSuthar how would I then add more results to the array? Like this? `[tmp addObject: @[@{@"name": @"matt", @"genre" : @"Photography"}]];` ?

Comment: (Hint:  Do `NSLog(@"%@", something);`, not `NSLog(something);`.)

Comment: @HotLicks Ohhh yes yes I was trying it in NSLog. Thanks for correction. :)

Comment: @Maximilian if you are going to add more result in NSArray using some loop then use NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Maximilian - You can use `[]` notation to modify an array/dictionary, but the array/dictionary must be mutable.  And I don't know of a way to add entries to the end of an array with that notation.

Comment: But this doesn't work: `NSMutableArray* tmp = @[@{@"name": _blogName, @"genre" : _genret}, @{@"name": @"jamie", @"genre" : @"Art"}];` ?

Comment: @Maximilian You will need to initialize it first after that you can use `addObject` method for adding more values in it. `NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`.

Comment: So like this? `_tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [_tmp addObject: @[@{@"name": @"matt", @"genre" : @"Photography"}]];`

Comment: Where _tmp is a NSMutableArray in the .h

Comment: Like this `_tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [_tmp addObject: @{@"name": @"matt", @"genre" : @"Photography"}];` Here we are adding NSDictionary inside array.

Answer (score 0):

use this code i hope help you :

```
 for (NSDictionary *data in jsonObjects) {


            NSString *name_data           =  [data objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSString *secteur_data      =  [data objectForKey:@"genre"];
            NSString *société_data      =  [data objectForKey:@"info"];

     DictionaryOfname = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [data objectForKey:@"name"],@"name",
                                  [data objectForKey:@"genre"],@"genre",
                                 [data objectForKey:@"info"],@"info",
                                   nil];

            [Listeofname addObject:DictionaryOfname];
    }
```

Comment: I can't see that even compiling.

Comment: What does `[    objectForKey:@"name"];` do then?

Comment: And leading caps should not be used for variable names in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You can as @Yogesh Suthar suggested and Can access using `valueForKeyPath` or just `valueForKey` Method.

```
NSArray * tmp = @[
                      @{@"name": @"matt", @"genre" : @"Photography"},
                      @{@"name": @"jamie", @"genre" : @"Art"}
                 ];


    NSLog(@"name is : %@", tmp[0][@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"name is : %@", [tmp valueForKeyPath:@"name"][0]);
```